# Numbering Duplicates with sequential numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Is this something which is possible in MS Access or SQL Server? I tried it in different ways using `GROUP BY` clause.

I want to find out the duplicates (concatenating Sales Order and Item) with the sequential number. Column 'schedule' is what I am looking for.

[image: duplicates numbering]

Comment: Minor text formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample data .You will get exact answer you need..

```
Begin Tran
create table sales
(
salesorder varchar(15),
item varchar(5)
)

insert into sales values('3040117007',1)
 insert into sales values('3040117007',1)
  insert into sales values('3040117007',1)



insert into sales values('3040179299',1)
 insert into sales values('3040179299',1)
  insert into sales values('3040182496',1)
  insert into sales values('3040182496',1)
  insert into sales values('3040182496',1)
  insert into sales values('3040182496',1)

select * from sales


;With CTE(Schedule,salesorder,item,concats)
as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by salesorder,item ORDER BY salesorder )
AS duplicates,salesorder,item,salesorder+''+item
FROM sales
)
--Now get Duplicate Records
select 'Duplicate_Records'* FROM CTE
WHERE Schedule > 1

rollback tran
```

Replace this query==>
"select 'Duplicate_Records'* FROM CTE
    WHERE Schedule > 1"

by this one "select 'All_Records'* FROM CTE" to get all records

Answer (score 2):

Use SQL CTE expression to get concat Duplicate values

Let us keep ur table name as **sales** and columnname as **Salesorder**,item,concat

```
With CTE(Duplicates,item,concat)
as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by salesorder,item ORDER BY salesorder )
AS duplicates,item, salesorder+''+item
FROM sales 
)
--Now Delete Duplicate Records
select * FROM CTE
WHERE duplicates > 1
```

Try this it will work.

Comment: This will only work on SQL Server, not in Access SQL.

Comment: Santhosa  has asked,to delete duplicate in any one platform.@cjb110

Comment: huh, no he didn't, he wants to number duplicates not delete them.

Comment: @Kavin. Thanks. unfortunately i get the error message saying below.                          Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: This was the answer I needed, and for the record works fine without the With and CTE statements. i.e.
`SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by salesorder,item ORDER BY salesorder ) as duplicates
,item
, salesorder+''+item
--,othervaluesfromsourcestable (optional, i needed to keep more that just the partition vars)
--INTO DEST_TABLE (optional to save it somewhere)
FROM sales 
--WHERE duplicates > 1 (optional to keep only dupes)`